# CMake binary directory of a subdirectory

Tags: cmake

My project structure is like

```
library
|
--executables
```

In order to make debugging easier, I want to add a custom target in executables' CMakeList which copies `$<TARGET_FILE:library>` to the output directory of executables.

I know I could just use `$<TARGET_FILE_DIR:exe1>` where exe1 is the name of one of the executables. But here I want a solution regardless of executable names.

Answer (score 1):

You can use CMake command add_custom_command

```
add_custom_command(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} POST_BUILD
                           COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy
                           ${libFullPath} $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:${PROJECT_NAME}>/${lib}.dll)
```